# pandas - Subtract 2 similar pivot table of data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a 36 rows x 36 columns dataframe of pivot table which I transform using code below:

```
df_pivoted = pd.pivot_table(df,index='From',columns='To',values='count')
df_pivoted.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

I transpose the same dataframe  using this code:

```
df_trans = df_pivoted.transpose()
```

and want to substract those two dataframes with this code:

```
new_pivoted = df_pivoted - df_trans
```

It gives me 72 rows x 72 columns dataframe with NaN value in all cell.

Then I try to use other code:

```
delta = df_pivoted.subtract(df_trans, fill_value=0)
```

However, it yields 72 rows x 72 columns with dataframe that looks like this:
[image]

Please help me to find the difference between the original dataframe with the transpose dataframe.

Comment: Are Columns and Index the same for df_pivoted?

Comment: you need to add code to your question that generates df similar to yours. If columns == index you'll have 36*36 df as a result of subtraction

Comment: what happens for your `delta` if you create `df_trans` such as `df_trans = pd.DataFrame(data=df_pivoted.transpose().values, index=df_pivoted.index, columns = df_pivoted.columns)`

Answer (score 1):

After transforming of you DataFrame (pivot table) you have new DataFrame where columns become Indices and vise versa. Now when you subtract on df from another Pandas use columns and Indices and fill NaN in the rest.

if you need to subtract values no matter of index and columns use:

```
delta = df_pivoted.values - df_trans.values
```

If you want to keep Columns and Index of df_trans in df_pivoted:

```
df_trans = pd.DataFrame(data=df_pivoted.transpose().values, 
                        index=df_pivoted.index,
                        columns = df_pivoted.columns)

delta = df_pivoted - df_trans
```

Now simple subtraction works.

Hope that helps!